Calculating sample size based on a 2 x 2 x 2 repeated measures ANOVA using G Power
I am planning on doing a 2 (A: a1, a2) x 2 (B: b1, b2) x 2 (C: c1, c2)repeated measures ANOVA where A and B are within subject factors and C is a between subject factor.
In G Power, I suppose the "number of groups"= 2 (due to 2 levels of between subject factor; c1, c2) and "number of measurements"= 4 (as a1, a2, b1, b2 will be measured in all participants)?
I also input the following:

effect size f= 0.25
α = 0.05
1-β = 0.95
corr among rep measures=0.5 (default)
nonspherity correlation=1 (default)

Then the total sample size I got was 36. This seem like a very small sample size for a 2x2x2 repeated measures ANOVA? Especially with only 18 participants in each group.
Or is the "number of measurements" supposed to be 2 due to two within-subject factors (A & B)?
Thank you!

Generally, "number of groups" means the number of levels of the between-subjects factor and "number of measurements" means the number of levels of the within-subjects (repeated) factor.
Unfortunately G*Power cannot currently calculate power for designs with more than one within-subject factor (hence, "number of measurements" refers to the levels of the sole within-factor that you can enter). Check out other resources such as Superpower, or consider simulation.
Another issue here is that you are probably using the GPower default for effect size metric. In the GPower RM-ANOVA calculation with the defaults, f=.25 is actually a huge effect size. Change the metric from "Options" into "As in Cohen (1988) - recommended" and then enter .25 into the effect size box. This represents medium effect size and should give you more realistic sample size that corresponds to what most other approaches and software give.
But, this doesn't solve the issue that you can't test a design with 2 within-subject factors with Gpower sadly.
